# Most of my ext4 Linux Filesystem partition is read-only? How to make it writable?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ext4, read-only

[image: Disk Partitions]

I have dual booted my computer into Windows and Ubuntu. My SSD is divided into two partitions. One contains the Ubuntu files and the other Windows files. The HDD is my data drive. I have stopped Fast Boot on Windows earlier because I was facing read-only issues with my HDD partitions. It got that fixed. But recently I encountered the same problem with my Computer partition.

[image: Computer Partition]

I am not allowed to make folders or save any files inside the Computer disk or inside most of its folders. A few days back I tried to customise my vim. I tried to paste a file within the vim folder (/usr/share/vim/vim81). But it is not allowed. Similarly, many such places in the Computer partition is not allowing me to do so.

Below I tried to make a new folder inside the Computer partition, and also within `/usr` folder, but it is not allowed.

[image: New Folder not allowed within Computer partition]

[image: New Folder not allowed within usr folder (/usr)]

On my other pc with Ubuntu, I am all allowed to do this, but not on this one. And also this is the only user on Ubuntu on this PC. Help me to make Ubuntu allow make folders in the computer folder.

Comment: You've provided no product or release details.  Assuming you didn't mount the *file-system* as read-only; a *file-system* only flips from RW (read-write) to RO (read-only) when errors are detected; with messages appearing in logs (or terminal if you're using commands) showing the reason; which usually means you need to *file-system* check (ie. `fsck`). It's done to prevent data-loss.  Did you look for reason?

Comment: It is not read-only. You need sudo to create files in `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file system is not read only. It is writable, but in Linux, not everybody can write anywhere. Please learn a little about Linux permissions.

By default, a user has write permissions in his own home folder only, and in removable drives if the drive is formatted with a file system that does not support file permissions.

The system administration can write anywhere on the file system. On Ubuntu, the first user that was created on the system has administrator permissions.

You should read yourself in a little bit on the basics before adventuring with a new operating system: https://help.ubuntu.com/ contains documentation that is very accessible for new users.